# Java: Use String as part of source code

Tags: java, boolean, evaluate

Today I have a question that I had on my mind for years now.
Consider you have the following evaluation in Java:

```
new EvaluationListener(){  
    public boolean evaluate(boolean[] b){
        return b[0] || b[1];
    }
}
```

I am using this code in my program for evaluating terms of different boolean values of b[0] and b[1], but that doesn't matter at all here.
**At the moment I am writing the evaluations into the source code, let the program run and watch the result in the command line.**
**Now I am wondering how I could implement the evaluation into command line. I would like to be able to enter an evaluation term into the command line, read it with BufferedReader etc. instead of writing it into the source code.**

Is there any way to do so? I thought it would be possible by using some sort of variable aliases like $b0$. But how can I pass logical OR and AND and NOT to the program?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm not sure I really understood your question, but if you want to pass the boolean values as well as the operand you could use the `args` at `main()` method.

Comment: Search for 'Java', 'Expression' and 'Evaluate'

Comment: @Caumons If I understand correctly, he is looking for some sort of Java REPL (but it's not really clear).

Comment: While reading the thread given by @Nick Holt, I am wondering if I need a parser?

Comment: Look at the `javax.script` API - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html

Comment: If the actual process of evaluating expressions is of any interest, then check GNU coreutils expr.c source code (I ported it to Java once for fun): http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/expr.c;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of expression evaluation with Java's script API:

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();

ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
scriptEngine.put("b1", true);
scriptEngine.put("b2", false);

System.out.println(scriptEngine.eval("b1 || b2"));
System.out.println(scriptEngine.eval("b1 && b2"));
```

When run, this code prints:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's exactely what I looked for.  
Can you tell me what the sign '^' does? Using it, it returns 1 instead of "true" or "false". Are there any further signs to use except '!' ?